# Join tables on columns of composite foreign / primary key in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, natural-join

```
CREATE TABLE subscription (
   magazine_id bigint,
   user_id     bigint,
   PRIMARY KEY (magazine_id, user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE delivery (
   magazine_id bigint,
   user_id     bigint,
   FOREIGN KEY (subscription) REFERENCES subscription (magazine_id, user_id)
);
```

What is a good way to query for deliveries given a particular subscription? Is there a way to assign a column name to `PRIMARY KEY (magazine_id, user_id)` and the corresponding foreign key so that I can query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
JOIN delivery ON (delivery.subscription_fk = delivery.subscription_pk);
```

Note: I can write something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscription
JOIN delivery ON (delivery.magazine_id = subscription.magazine_id
              AND delivery.user_id = subscription.user_id);
```

However, I am under the impression that there is a less verbose way to achieve this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   subscription
NATURAL JOIN delivery;
```

Quoting [the manual on `SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

> `NATURAL`
>
> `NATURAL` is shorthand for a `USING` list that mentions all columns in the two tables that have the same names.

It would work for your test setup, but it's **not strictly doing what you ask for**. The connection is based on all columns sharing the same name. Foreign keys are not considered. The cases where `NATURAL JOIN` is a good idea are few and far between.

#### Simplify code / less verbose

For starters, you could use table aliases and you don't need parentheses around the join conditions with `ON` (unlike with `USING`):

```
SELECT *
FROM   subscription s
JOIN   delivery     d ON d.magazine_id = s.magazine_id
                     AND d.user_id = s.user_id;
```

Since column names in the join conditions are identical, you can further simplify with `USING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   subscription s
JOIN   delivery     d USING (magazine_id, user_id);
```

There is no syntax variant making joins based on foreign key constraints automatically. You would have to query the system catalogs and build the SQL dynamically.

Comment: Would there be any particular advantage to creating a custom type for this scenario?

Comment: @IamIC: Not sure where you are going with that. You might start a new question with details. You can always link to this one for context - and optionally leave a comment here.

Comment: This is a great answer because it shows how you *can* do it but also explicitly calls out that, while it *might* work for a given setup, it isn't because of any automatic  FK magic

Comment: this is a great answer, but my 2 cents ... please don't use Natural Join and be a little more explicit with Using ... it will go a long way to make the code much more maintainable..

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `delivery` has two columns representing the foreign key? Then it should work like with a non-composite primary key `SELECT * FROM subscription JOIN delivery ON (delivery.magazine_id = subscription.magazine_id AND delivery.user_id = subscription.user_id)`.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to write this so that the query is less verbose. I was under the impression that this could be done